# Identify processes running inside Docker, in Process List

Tags: centos, docker, centos7, top, ps

I realize that processes that run inside Docker containers appear on the hosts' process list:

```
# ps aux | grep mariadb
root     12486  0.0  0.0 112812   976 pts/0    S+   14:47   0:00 grep --color=auto mariadb
```

Is there a way to identify whether a process is running on the Host or on a Docker container, or a way to filter the Docker processes out?

Comment: You can check the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659129/docker-processes-shown-on-host-process-list

Comment: @basekat Thank you. I did try Googling several expressions hoping to find my answer, but I was only getting results of "docker ps" and other unhelpful stuff. That post does not seem to answer my question, however :) just explains what I already know.

Comment: `cat /proc/PID/cgroup`, where PID is a process' PID on the host, tells you if a given process runs in a Docker container (from https://blog.stangroome.com/2017/12/05/inspecting-docker-container-processes-from-the-host/).

Comment: @berndbausch Very interesting! I may have the answer there! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer.

To filter processes that are not running in Docker processes, we can use this:

`ps -e -o pid,comm,cgroup | grep -v "/docker/"`

So, for example, if I want to kill all "php-fpm" processes that are not running inside Docker, I can do:

`kill -9 $(ps -e -o pid,comm,cgroup | grep -v "/docker/" | awk '$2 == "php-fpm" {print $1}')`

Answer (score 0):

If I quickly want to see what processes were started by what, I typically use a tool like `htop` (in tree mode by pressing F5), or `pstree`.

The output from `pstree` will look a bit like this:

```
systemd─┬─VGAuthService
        ├─abrt-dbus───3*[{abrt-dbus}]
        ├─abrt-watch-log
        ├─abrtd
        ├─chronyd
        ├─crond
        ├─dockerd─┬─docker-containe─┬─4*[docker-containe─┬─pause]
        │         │                 │                    └─9*[{docker-containe}]]
        │         │                 ├─docker-containe─┬─kube-apiserver───16*[{kube-apiserver}]
        │         │                 │                 └─9*[{docker-containe}]
        │         │                 ├─docker-containe─┬─kube-scheduler───14*[{kube-scheduler}]
        │         │                 │                 └─10*[{docker-containe}]
        │         │                 ├─docker-containe─┬─kube-controller───13*[{kube-controller}]
        │         │                 │                 └─10*[{docker-containe}]
        │         │                 ├─4*[docker-containe─┬─pause]
        │         │                 │                    └─10*[{docker-containe}]]
        │         │                 ├─docker-containe─┬─kube-proxy───12*[{kube-proxy}]
        │         │                 │                 └─9*[{docker-containe}]
        │         │                 ├─docker-containe─┬─node_exporter───31*[{node_exporter}]
        │         │                 │                 └─10*[{docker-containe}]
        │         │                 └─29*[{docker-containe}]
        │         └─47*[{dockerd}]
```

Which easily shows what processes are started by what.

`htop` lives within the in EPEL Repo, on RHEL.
`pstree` is installed by the `psmisc` package.

This isn't the most technical answer, but the best answer seems to already exist in a comment.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the tips (I upvoted you). However, I'm looking for a way to do it straight with "ps", so I can easily get a list of PIDs, to pass to `kill`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

cgroup 2.0 doesn't indicate that you're running in a docker container, nor does it work under Docker Desktop on Mac.

root@8a1d175a0b6c:/# ps -e -o pid,comm,cgroup
PID COMMAND         CGROUP
1 tini            -
7 java            -
3081 bash            -
3282 ps              -

You can look for /.dockerenv, but it's an empty file, so there's no unified, reliable way to get your own docker container Id.  The Docker team really dropped the ball on this one.

Comment: That's not what is asked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/531201)